# Can I used Google Authenticator with Radius and VMwareview

Tags: vpn, google, radius

We're looking to add 2 factor and one of the options is google authenticator and I was wondering if we can attach that to a radius server attached to our VM infrastructure for remote access.

All the options I've found so far are RSA key or OpenOTP or SMS passcode, which are things we can go to, but we would like to use google if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Authenticate stems from the OATH (Open Authentication) group, and is based on [RFC 4266](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) and [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238).  You could implement it using Pluggable Authentication Modules on your RADIUS server.

Check out [this](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/oath-toolkit-help/2011-06/msg00007.html) thread and [this](http://it.isevil.org/blog/2011/11/13/authentication-service-using-google-authenticator/).